# Changing inclusion of country/state labels at different zoom levels?

Tags: google-maps

In Google Maps static API (and the other APIs as far as I can tell), at zoom level 7 the country label for USA disappears and at zoom level 8 the labels for individual states disappear.

I am interested in generating maps at zoom level 8 but retaining the country and state labels. I realise the labels are not entirely appropriate to this zoom level but I would like them to be visible if you happened to view the map at the appropriate location.

Is there any way of acheiving this with the Google Maps API?

I have tried

```
style=feature:administrative.country|element:labels|visibility:on&stylefeature:administrative.province|element:labels|visibility:on
```

but this doesn't add the labels I want at zoom level 8. My suspicion is that this simply can't be done, but maybe someone knows a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use styled maps to change that. But you can add them yourself to the map at the higher zoom levels.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bf7qqwqw/1/)

[proof of concept with all 50 states, but probably need to tweak some of the locations](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bf7qqwqw/4/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.9, -97.092877),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = "zoom="+map.getZoom();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
  });
  // 35.930648,-97.166119
  var myOptions = {
    content: "OKLAHOMA",
    boxStyle: {
      border: "none",
      textAlign: "center",
      fontSize: "14pt",
      width: "50px",
      color: "grey"
    },
    disableAutoPan: true,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-25, 0),
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(36.05, -97.4),
    closeBoxURL: "",
    isHidden: false,
    pane: "mapPane",
    enableEventPropagation: true
  };
  var ibLabel = new InfoBox(myOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    console.log("zoom=" + map.getZoom());
    document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = "zoom=" + map.getZoom();
    if (map.getZoom() == 8) {
      ibLabel.open(map);
    } else {
      ibLabel.close();
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 98%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<div id="zoom"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: That's fantastic! What sources are you using for the lat/long data for the label position? Just sampling it from the zoom level 7 map?
Is there a way of doing this with the static map API?

Comment: I just used a "state" KML file I had that looked like it was close to the labels on the existing map (which is why they may need to be tweaked).  Doing this with the static maps API will be more difficult (you just get an image from the static map API)